# Настройка удаленного подключения к компьютерам в локальной сети

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server, rdp, domain

1. Есть 10 компьютеров, находящихся в одной локальной сети
2. Сеть в домене
3. Есть два контроллера домена
4. Компьютеры на Win7/8/10, контроллер домена на windows server 2012

Как лучше всего настроить удаленное подключение ко всем компьютерам в локалке?

Я знаю, что можно пройтись по каждому компьютеру и там вручную настроить RDP, но может быть есть элегантные, и, самое главное, безопасные варианты настройки удаленного подключения?

Comment: `wikipedia://Групповая политика`. Стеркин и winitpro ждут тебя с распростёртыми объятиями.

Answer (score 0):

Для настройки необходимо выполнить 3 шага:

1. Создать группу безопасности (AD security group)
2. Создать групповую политику
3. Применить GPO к компьютерам домена

**Создание группы безопасности**

Создадим группу **RDP_computers** и добавим пользователей, которым будет разрешено входить на ВМ через протокол RDP. Для это заходим в оснастку *Active Directory — пользователи и компьютеры → Имя домена → Users*, щелкаем по нему правой кнопкой мыши и выбираем из доступных свойств Создать → Группа, вводим имя группы и нажимаем ОК

**Создание групповой политики**

Открываем оснастку управления групповыми политиками: *Пуск→ Средства администрирование Windows → Управление групповой политикой*. Создаём организационный контейнер для компьютерами с RDP. Контейнер можно создать через оснастку Управление групповой политикой либо Active Directory — пользователи и компьютеры.

Политика применяется на организационный контейнер VDI в котором располагаются подконтрольные компьютеры, поэтому раскрываем домен, находим контейнер, щелкаем по нему правой кнопкой мыши и выбираем из доступных свойств Создать объект групповой политики в этом домене и связать его.... Назовём его **Enable RDP**. Открываем политику на редактирование и переходим в элементы конфигурирования настроек на компьютер: *Enable RDP → Конфигурация компьютера → Политики → Конфигурация Windows → Параметры безопасности → Группы с ограниченным доступом.* Щелкаем правой кнопкой мыши вызываем свойства и выбираем Добавить группу → Обзор, далее через Обзор находим созданную группу: **RDP_computers**. По окончании нажимаем кнопку Применить и OK

В окне **Свойства** группы настраиваем членства к другой группе. Нажимаем Добавить находим группу **Пользователи удалённого рабочего стола** и добавляем. Нажимаем ОК.
[image: GPO_RDP]

Теперь активируем галочку разрешить подключение к удалённому рабочему столу в свойства системы. Для этого внесём изменения в групповую политику Enable RDP.

Enable RDP → Конфигурация компьютера → Настройка → Конфигурация Windows → Реестр, создаем новый ключ, Создать – Элемент реестра.

Значения настроек

```
Действие:Обновить
Куст: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Путь раздела:System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server
Имя параметра: fDenyTSConnections
Тип параметра: REG_DWORD
Значение: 00000000
```

[image: GPO-registry]
По окончании настроек нажимаем кнопку Применить и OK для принятия изменений. Теперь чтобы политика применилась на рабочие станции в организационном контейнере VDI они должны быть перезагружены.